# How to create a regular expression for numeric strings that should include only 0-9 digits, comma, dot, plus, minus and whitespaces?

Tags: c#, regex, numeric

I've had one for everything but spaces, that worked great:

```
new Regex("[^0-9-+,.\r]");
```

But adding spaces seemed to be a problem.
I don't need any validity check more than that.

Comment: For space you can use `\s`

Comment: The caret ^ at the beginning of the character class means to look for everything but that list of characters. There's no quantifier afterwards, so your regex will only match one character.

Comment: Try this `^[\d,\. +-]+$`

Comment: Your regex says everything *except* what you listed. Not sure if that's what you want. Anyways, I believe `\s` covers `\r`, `\t`, and `\n`. Also `\d` covers `0-9`.

Comment: (You need an escape `\\r` in your example)

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like what you want (warning: untested)

```
new Regex("[\\d-\\+,\\.\\s+]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches almost all what you do not need as the `^` *negates* the symbols in the character class. It matches all symbols other that digits, comma, period, hyphen, plus, and a carriage return.

Note that a carriage return is not all whitespace that you can match with `\s`. If you do not want to match line breaks, use `\p{Zs}` instead of `\s`.

> How to create a regular expression for numeric strings that should include only 0-9 digits, comma, dot, plus, minus and whitespaces?

If you need to match a complete string that may be empty:

```
^[0-9,.+\s-]*$
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B0-9%2C.%2B%5Cs-%5D*%5Cr%3F%24&i=-1234.677%0D%0A%2B7889.887%2C876%20%2B%20876%2C5%20-%20567.677%2C678%0D%0A&o=m). If a string should contain at least 1 symbol, use `^[0-9,.+\s-]+$` (note the `+` quantifier at the end).

Regex breakdown:

- `^`- the start of a string
- `[0-9,.+\s-]*` - 0 or more symbols...

  - `0-9` - a digit
  - `,` - a comma
  - `.` - a dot
  - `+` - a literal plus
  - `\s` - any (Unicode, too) whitespace
  - `-` - a literal hyphen (minus).
- `$` - end of string.

In C#,

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^[0-9,.+\s-]*$");
```

In a verbatim string literal you do not have to escape the backslashes as they are treated as literals.

If you plan to *remove* all symbols so that numbers, periods, commas, hyphens and pluses remain, just negate it and remove anchors:

```
[^0-9,.+\s-]+
```

See [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E0-9%2C.%2B%5Cs-%5D%2B&i=-12%2434.677%20hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh%0D%0A%2B788%239.887%2C876%20%2B%20876%2C5%20-%20567.677%2C678%0D%0A&r=&o=m)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but this solution still didn't accept spaces. I used: `@"[0-9-+,.\s]"` eventually

Comment: So, you are using `Regex.IsMatch`? You just need `Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^[0-9,.+\s-]*$")`. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/X4fpYZ).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an alternative to Regex here, you can also use LINQ

```
public static bool ContainsOnlyAllowedChars(string str, string charsAllowed = "0123456789,.+- ")
{
    return str.All(c => charsAllowed.Contains(c));
}
```

Usage

```
string myInput = "4,.";
Console.WriteLine(ContainsOnlyAllowedChars(myInput)); //outputs true

myInput = "a4,.";
Console.WriteLine(ContainsOnlyAllowedChars(myInput)); //outputs false
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason, tis solution didn't accept spaces.

Comment: That's strange, I tried it with a space and it worked. Are you sure you included the space before the final `"`? (that wasn't a typo :D)

Answer (score 0):

The solution, eventually:

```
private static bool IsTextNumeric(string text)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^0-9-+,.\s]");// regex that matches disallowed text
        return !regex.IsMatch(text);
    }
```

While [\s includes \r](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.90).aspx).